# i18n JAVA character encoding

Tags: java, internationalization

I have a Java (Java 7) program using i18n with properties files, but I cannot insert emoticon or others "non ordinary" letters because Java prints `?`. But when I use, for instance:

```
package res;

import java.util.ListResourceBundle;

public class Bundle_it_IT extends ListResourceBundle {

    @Override
    protected Object[][] getContents() {
        return new Object[][] {
                {"hello", "Hello, “ \ uD83D\ uDE42 \ uD83D\ uDE0A\ uD83D\ uDE00\ uD83D\ uDE01"},
                {"ourfeatures", new String[] {"Test 1", "Test2", "test 3"
        };
    }
}
```

Java is able to print all without question marks.

Is there a way in order to use proprieties files even for "strange symbol"? And encoding of the properties files is ASCHI?

The main class is:

```
package testi18nv1;

import res.Bundle_it_IT;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Locale locale_it_IT = new Locale("it", "IT");
        Locale locale_ru_RU = new Locale("ru", "RU");

        Bundle_it_IT bundle_it_IT =  new Bundle_it_IT();

        ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("res.bundle", locale_it_IT);

        System.out.println(resourceBundle.getString("hello"));
        System.out.println(bundle_it_IT.getString("hello"));
    }
}
```

I have tried to use Russian letter on properties files but java print question marks.

Comment: "...because Java prints ?..." is it that Java prints that, or is it that the terminal prints that because it's not configured to use a suitable charset?

Comment: The terminal is the same, but in one case I get the information from properties and the second case from  Object[][]

Comment: Documentation of `PropertyResourceBundle`: "**Note:**  ... Constructing a PropertyResourceBundle instance from an InputStream requires that the input stream be encoded in ISO-8859-1. In that case, characters that cannot be represented in ISO-8859-1 encoding must be represented by Unicode Escapes as defined in section 3.3 of The Java™ Language Specification whereas the other constructor which takes a Reader does not have that limitation."

Answer (score 2):

Originally *.properties were in Latin-1, ISO-8859-1.

The newer java versions first try UTF-8.
So you would need to update from Java 7 to a newer version. Which is not problematic.

You could also keep a properties file in UTF-8, say xxx.utf8props and convert and copy them to xxx.properties from the src to the build directory. This can be done with the java SE tool **native2ascii**. (Like `\uD83D`)

More cumbersome is to change your code and use your own loading with the class Properties.

But really Java 7 is no longer production quality.

Comment: Good Answer. Plus, a note: In Java 18+, UTF-8 will be the default encoding for nearly all purposes, across platforms. See [*JEP 400: UTF-8 by Default*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/400).